# Dialog - Select a file with specific name

Tags: java, file, filter, dialog

is there any way to allow to select a file with a specific name in Java? I'm trying with this code, setting the name and the extension in the filter string, but it doesn't work

```
    configExplorerBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e){
             FileDialog dialogExplorer = new FileDialog(getShell());
             dialogExplorer.setFilterPath(destinationField.getText());
             dialogExplorer.setText("Seleccione un archivo...");
             String[] filterExt = { "config*.xml"}; //1
             dialogExplorer.setFilterExtensions(filterExt);

             String path = dialogExplorer.open();
             if (path != null) {
               configField.setText(path);
               nextConfig=true;
             }
             else{
               nextConfig=false;
             }
             checkStatus();
         }
     });
```

I know that I can write "*.xml" and let the user to choose, but I prefer force him/her to select a file with that name.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are forcing the user to select a file with the same exact name why even ask him to choose the file at all?

Comment: I didn't see this way, I can ask for the directory of this file and access to it. Maybe my question was silly… Sorry!

Comment: You can always save the file relative to the directory your executable is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense to ask the user for an XML file and only an XML file(but you already know how to do this), you want to ask the user for ONLY 1 specific XML file that can only have 1 specific name... why even ask the user in the first place? The whole point of a dialogue is to ask the user to choose a file. Perhaps you just want to skip that step and go right to...

```
new File("file path");
```

You don't have to ask the user for the file to retrieve the file or create the file.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html